# I'm failing to select the check box from a table

Tags: html, ruby, web, automation, capybara

I'm failing to select a check box from table; I have 32 check boxes and I want to check role2, role3

Please help me with how to select role2, role3 check boxes. 
Below is my source code:

```
 <tr>
    <td class='first'>

        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role2' value='Role2' />

    </td>
    <td>
        <b>Home View Search</b>
    </td>
    <td class='last'>
        View and perform search operations from Home page.
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='first'>

        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role3' value='Role3' />

    </td>
    <td>
        <b>System Manage Admin</b>
    </td>
    <td class='last'>
        Create, update and delete administrators.
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
</select>

    </div>

</td>
<td valign='top'>
    <div style='height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
        <table width='100%' class='checkbox' id='functionTable'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2' width='560'>
                        TM Functions
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        TM Administration Functions
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td class='first'>

                        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role0' value='Role0' />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Home Switch Owners</b>
                    </td>
                    <td class='last'>
                        Ability to switch owners clicking on owner name from Home screen.
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class='first'>

                        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role1' value='Role1' />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Home Accept Decline Vendor Invite</b>
                    </td>
                    <td class='last'>
                        Accept or decline vendor invitations from Home page.
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class='first'>

                        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role2' value='Role2' />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Home View Search</b>
                    </td>
                    <td class='last'>
                        View and perform search operations from Home page.
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class='first'>

                        <input type='checkbox' onclick=CheckboxClick(this); name='Role3' value='Role3' />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>System Manage Admin</b>
                    </td>
                    <td class='last'>
                        Create, update and delete administrators.
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are visible on the page then the following should check Role2 and Role 3

```
page.check('Role2')
page.check('Role3')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

webelement element = driver.findelement(by.xpath(//[@id='tablename'/tbody/tr/td[2])).click();
webelement element = driver.findelement(by.xpath(//[@id='tablename'/tbody/tr/td[3])).click();

make sure your row numbers are correct